# How about instead of closing questions some questions can be 'flagged' in other ways?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How about instead of closing questions some questions can be 'flagged' in other ways?

How about instead of closing questions as the main tool available, some questions can be 'flagged' in other ways? For instance, why not allow mods or those with enough rep to vote on a question as entertainment? The result of a question being flagged as entertainment would be to cap or eliminate the rep earned by populist questions such as the "Jon Skeet Facts".

Answer (score 5):

> The result of a question being flagged as entertainment would be to cap or eliminate the rep earned by populist questions such as the "Jon Skeet Facts".

The rep isn't the biggest problem - no one gained massive amounts of reputation from that question, since it turned CW early on. Now it's on Meta, so no one's getting SO rep for it...

The biggest problem is simply noise. Closing isn't the solution to that, either - deletion is. Closing is sort of a staging area, where bad questions sit until someone gets around to deleting or improving them.

If a question is truly inappropriate, flag it for moderator attention - that feature exists *now*, and moderators can put a question and all responses into CW (no rep) mode, move them to a more appropriate site, or instantly delete them.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn a question into a CW, this will prevent any rep on "fun" questions.

A feature like this could encourage people to post questions that don't have a clear answer, since there is a feature that relates to that.